# Can anyone help me out? My code print 0 every time input a different value; my code is supposed to print number of coins

Tags: cs50

In problem set6 I am required to ask user for an input( a float) and then use the input to calculate number of coin the use owe. In my code I used modulo function in a while to increment number of coin by one. Unfortunately I don't get the outcome I expected. Can anyone assist?

Below is my code

```
# ask the user for change owed
from cs50 import get_float
while True:
    change = get_float("Change owed:")
    if change > 0:
        break

#compute quarter
coin = 0
while change % 0.25 >= 0.25:
    change = change - 0.25
    coin += 1

#compute dime
while change % 0.1 >= 0.1:
    change = change - 1
    coint += 1

#compute nickel
while change % 0.5 >= 0.5:
    change = change - 0.5
    coin += 1

#compute pennies
while change % 0.1 >= 0.1:
    change = change - 0.1
    coin += 1

print(coin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code lines like:

```py
change % 0.1 >= 0.1
```

always will be `false`, because any remainder after division `change` on some `k` is less than `k`.
Your coin always will be 0. Also try to think about order of while loops in your algo, seems it should be differ.